# why doesn't css file affect syling html file sent from python server made using socket?

Tags: python, css, sockets

I have python server using socket. The code can be found here https://github.com/aminabcd/python-server/blob/master/new.py, an html file and a css file can be found respectively at https://github.com/aminabcd/python-server/blob/master/login.html and https://github.com/aminabcd/python-server/blob/master/login.css.

When html file is opened from a local machine, the page looks like
[image]
but when it is served from my python server it look like
[image]
headers captured by firebug are as 
[image]
and 
[image]

now, my question is why css file has no effect on html file when served from python server?

Comment: You didn't close your link tag ( `<link rel="stylesheet" href="login.css" />` ) It probably won't fix the issue, but can't make anything worse neither ;)

Comment: Also can I see what's in the response tab of your GET login.css request in your browser console ?

Comment: thanks for your quick attention, I have got the solution, the problem was in the response header, whatever the file was, I set the content-type as 'html', anyway, thanks